# Ajax form with codeigniter validation

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to make ajax form validation work in codeigniter.

Form and ajax are both in **views/products/addproducts**,

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submitProducts").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataString = $("#add-products-bulk-form").serialize();
        var url="products/addproducts";
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>"+url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:dataString,
            success:function (res) {
                res=$.parseJSON(res);
                if($.isEmptyObject(res.error)){
                    alert(res.success);
                }else{
                    console.log("hasn't run form yet");
                }
            },  
      })
    })
    });    
    </script>
```

here is my **Products** controller:

```
public function addproducts()
    {
        $data['title'] = "Add Products";
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('products/addproducts');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        //form rules
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('name[]', 'Product Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('partnumber[]', 'Part number', 'required|is_unique[items.itemSKU]');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('msrp[]', 'MSRP', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            echo "did not pass validation";
            $errors = validation_errors();
            echo json_encode(['error'=>$errors]);
        }
        else
        { 
            echo "did pass validation";
            $this->product_model->add_products();
            echo json_encode(['success'=>'Record added successfully.']);
        }
    }
```

I don't get any response when I click submit button if I keep the code above way. But if I get rid of line **dataType:'json'**, I will get error

```
VM1679:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (addproducts:140)
    at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
```

If I get rid of both **dataType:'json'** and **res=$.parseJSON(res)**, when I enter a duplicated product and click submit, and console.log(res), I get the following in the console, It did return the res and the source code of the whole page addproducts.

```
    did not pass validation{"error":"<p>The Part number field must contain a unique value.<\/p>\n"}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

I did not paste the whole source code here. and res.success will alert undefined.

I have been stuck for days, please help. I will provide more details if needed.
Thanks!

Comment: You are loading a view (html) and returning JSON at the same time... jQuery dataType is set to best guess by default, you should only return JSON if thats what you want.... In short, remove: `$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('products/addproducts');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clean up my earlier comment...

```
public function addproducts()
{

    //form rules
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('name[]', 'Product Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('partnumber[]', 'Part number', 'required|is_unique[items.itemSKU]');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('msrp[]', 'MSRP', 'required');

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {

        $this->output->set_status_header(400);
        $errors = validation_errors();
        echo json_encode(['error'=>$errors]);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->output->set_status_header(200);
        $this->product_model->add_products();
        echo json_encode(['success'=>'Record added successfully.']);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the success callback to listen for a successful response and the error callback to listen for an error response...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submitProducts").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataString = $("#add-products-bulk-form").serialize();
            var url="products/addproducts";
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>"+url,
                dataType: 'json',
                data:dataString,
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.responseJSON.error);
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert(jqXHR.responseJSON.success);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I make ajax call with the same controller function, I divided the addproducts function into two functions as follow,and use ajax to call ajax_add_products function. it works now.

```
public function addproducts()
    {
        $data['title'] = "Add Products";
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('products/addproducts');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');


    }

    public function ajax_add_products(){
        //form rules
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('name[]', 'Product Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('partnumber[]', 'Part number', 'required|is_unique[items.itemSKU]');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('msrp[]', 'MSRP', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $errors = validation_errors();
            echo json_encode(['error'=>$errors]);
        }
        else
        { 
            $this->product_model->add_products();
            echo json_encode(['success'=>'Record added successfully.']);
        }
    }
```